# SAT like question format

Tags: lists, enumerate

How do I create question like those in SAT (with black and gray color) by my own enumerate design so like every time I write `\begin{myenumerate}` it will generate like those in SAT exams.  Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I construct two environments `question` and `choices` by using
the basic `list` environment provided that two columns mode is used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[width = 18cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcounter{question}
\newcounter{choice}
\setcounter{choice}{1}
\newenvironment{question}{%
  \stepcounter{question}%
  \noindent\colorbox{black}{\textcolor{white}{\makebox[1.5em][c]{\thequestion}}}%
  \colorbox{lightgray}{\phantom{\rule{\columnwidth-1.5em-\columnsep}{\heightof{1}}}}\par
  \begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength\itemindent{0pt}%
    \setlength\leftmargin{2em}%
    \setlength\labelwidth{0pt}%
    \setlength\labelsep{0pt}}%
    \item[]}%
{\end{list}}

\newenvironment{choices}{%
  \begin{list}{\Alph{choice})}{%
    \setlength\labelwidth{30pt}%
    \setlength\itemindent{0pt}%
    \setlength\leftmargin{2em}%
    \setlength\labelsep{10pt}%
    \usecounter{choice}}}%
  {\end{list}}
\setlength\columnseprule{0.5pt}
\begin{document}

\twocolumn
\begin{question}
  Which choice best describes what happens in the passage?
  \begin{choices}
    \item One character argues with another character who intrudes on her home.
    \item One character receives a surprising request from another character.
    \item One character reminisces about choices she has made over the years.
    \item One character criticizes another character for pursuing an unexpected course of action.
  \end{choices}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  Which choice best describes the developmental pattern of the passage?
  \begin{choices}
    \item A careful analysis of a traditional practice.
    \item A detailed depiction of a meaningful encounter.
    \item A definitive response to a series of questions.
    \item A cheerful recounting of an amazing anecdote.
  \end{choices}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  Which choice best describes what happens in the passage?
  \begin{choices}
    \item One character argues with another character who intrudes on her home.
    \item One character receives a surprising request from another character.
    \item One character reminisces about choices she has made over the years.
    \item One character criticizes another character for pursuing an unexpected course of action.
  \end{choices}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  Which choice best describes the developmental pattern of the passage?
  \begin{choices}
    \item A careful analysis of a traditional practice.
    \item A detailed depiction of a meaningful encounter.
    \item A definitive response to a series of questions.
    \item A cheerful recounting of an amazing anecdote.
  \end{choices}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  Which choice best describes what happens in the passage?
  \begin{choices}
    \item One character argues with another character who intrudes on her home.
    \item One character receives a surprising request from another character.
    \item One character reminisces about choices she has made over the years.
    \item One character criticizes another character for pursuing an unexpected course of action.
  \end{choices}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  Which choice best describes the developmental pattern of the passage?
  \begin{choices}
    \item A careful analysis of a traditional practice.
    \item A detailed depiction of a meaningful encounter.
    \item A definitive response to a series of questions.
    \item A cheerful recounting of an amazing anecdote.
  \end{choices}
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

[image]