# Digital SAT Question Format with Exercise Package

Tags: lists, exercises

I am working on a textbook using the exercise package. I would like for each exercise to look like the new digital SAT format. I worked off of ([SAT like question format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/691535/sat-like-question-format)) before realizing the exercise package would work better for my project. I am also printing our the answers at the end of the book by chapter/section with \shipoutAnswer. The new Digital SAT questions have this format.

[image: Digital SAT question]

I got pretty close with the MyChoice before switching to the exercise package but had some trouble with the smart box. I believe I will need to work with \renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader} to accomplish this with the exercise package. I appreciate any advice on how to accomplish this!

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}


\newcommand{\DrawSmartBox}[1][black]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
    \draw[#1, rounded corners]
      ($(bl)+(-2.5em,1.5em)$) rectangle
      ($(br)+(0,-.7em)$);}
}

\newcommand{\MyCorrectSmartChoice}[2][black]{\CorrectChoice \tikzmark{bl}#2\tikzmark{br}\DrawSmartBox[red]}

\newcommand{\MyChoice}[1]{\item \tikzmark{bl}#1\tikzmark{br}\DrawSmartBox}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[width = 18cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcounter{question}
\newcounter{choice}
\setcounter{choice}{1}
\newenvironment{question}{%
  \stepcounter{question}%
  \noindent\colorbox{black}{\textcolor{white}{\makebox[1.5em][c]{\thequestion}}}%
  \colorbox{lightgray}{\phantom{\rule{\columnwidth-1.5em-\columnsep}{\heightof{1}}}}\par
  \begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength\itemindent{0pt}%
    \setlength\leftmargin{0.0em}%
    \setlength\labelwidth{0pt}%
    \setlength\labelsep{0pt}}%
    \item[]}%
{\end{list}}

\usepackage{enumitem,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{align=left}
\newlist{choices}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[choices]{label=\Alph*,format=\ovalnode,align=left,itemsep=1.5em, itemindent=.5em}
\newcommand\ovalnode[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(circle.base)]\node[draw,circle,inner ysep=1pt,inner xsep=1pt](circle){\makebox[0.8em]{#1\vphantom{A}}};}
\let\choice\item

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
  Which choice best describes what happens in the passage?
  \begin{choices}
    \item One character argues with another character who intrudes on her home.
    \item One character receives a surprising request from another character.
    \item One character reminisces about choices she has made over the years.
    \item One character criticizes another character for pursuing an unexpected course of action.
  \end{choices}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  Which choice best describes the developmental pattern of the passage?
  \begin{choices}
    \item A careful analysis of a traditional practice.
    \item A detailed depiction of a meaningful encounter.
    \item A definitive response to a series of questions.
    \item A cheerful recounting of an amazing anecdote.
  \end{choices}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  Which choice best describes the developmental pattern of the passage?
  \begin{choices}
    \MyChoice{A careful analysis of a traditional practice.} 
    \MyChoice{A detailed depiction of a meaningful encounter.}
    \MyChoice{A definitive response to a series of questions. Get to a second line. Get to a second line. Get to a second line. Get to a second line. Get to a second line. Get to a second line. Get to a second line.}
    \MyChoice{A cheerful recounting of an amazing anecdote.}
  \end{choices}
\end{question}

\end{document}'
```

[image: mychoice shown in question 3]

Part of my current environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[cmintegrals, cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{
    label = {(\Alph*)},
    label-width=1.4em
    }

\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed]{exercise}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{Exercise}
\renewcommand{\AnswerName}{Exercise}
\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{Exercise} % register the counter for getting the total
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{Exercise}{section}
\counterwithin{Answer}{section}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totalex}
\usepackage{titleref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


% \renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{ \stepcounter{totalex}\ifnumcomp{\value{Exercise}}{=}{1}{\ifnumcomp{\thechapter}{=}{1}{}{\vspace{10pt}}\noindent\Large\textbf{Chapter\ \thechapter\ \currenttitle}\par\vspace{10pt}}{}\noindent\normalsize\bfseries\ExerciseName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB\par\medskip}

% make look like Digital SAT
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{ \stepcounter{totalex}\ifnumcomp{\value{Exercise}}{=}{1}{\ifnumcomp{\thechapter}{=}{1}{}{\vspace{10pt}}\noindent\Large\textbf{Chapter\ \thechapter\ \currenttitle}\\}{}\noindent\normalsize\bfseries\ExerciseName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB\\}


\begin{document}
    \section{Words in Context}
        % Words in context practice problem below:
            \begin{Exercise}
                What is the value of 2+5? 
                \begin{tasks}(4)
                \task 2
                \task 5
                \task\label{correctchoice}7
                \task 3
                \end{tasks}
                \end{Exercise}
                \begin{Answer}
                \ref{correctchoice} 7
                \end{Answer}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.